# MySQL UPDATE with JOIN extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I deal mostly with SQL server TSQL. I've been tasked with converting a TSQL sproc into a MySQL sproc. In TSQL, the following little update takes less than a fraction of a second. The same update in MySQL is taking 20 minutes or more.

```
UPDATE MyTempTable 
INNER JOIN ZipCode on ZipCode.SourceZip = pSourceZip
                  AND ZipCode.DestZip = pDestZip
SET 
    CT = ZipCode.GD 
WHERE
    ZipCode.Updated >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -365 DAY);
```

`pSourceZip` and `pDestZip` are parameters for the sproc. The Temporary table has 2 rows in it. ZipCode has 35,992,342 in it. ZipCode has an index on `SourceZip` and `DestZip`. I can run the following simple select and it returns instantly. `select * from ZipCode where SourceZip = pSourceZip and DestZip = pDestZip;` What am I missing on the update?

Comment: Do an explain on the update and you shall see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @Shadow that did help, thanks! Posted my own answer to help anyone who comes across something like this.

Comment: you can add an index to your temporary table then check your explain plan for performance bottlenecks

Answer (score 1):

`ZipCode` needs

```
INDEX(SourceZip, Updated, DestZip)
```

And the datatypes much match.  Certain mismatches are OK, but INT vs VARCHAR is not.

`varchar_col = int-constant` (as in `zip CHAR(5)` with `zip = 12345`) can't use `INDEX(zip)`.  Either change `CHAR(5)` to `MEDIUMINT` or change `12345` to `"12345"`.  (or both)

In your case, you have `pSourceZip` as a parameter to a Stored Routine?  Then it should have the same declaration as `ZipCode.SourceZip`.  (At least both char or both int.)

Answer (score 0):

The `ZipCode` table has `SourceZip` and `DestZip` defined as `varchar(5)`. The old TSQL sproc accepted the zip parameters as `int`, so I did the same thing in the MySQL sproc. I guess MySQL isn't as forgiving with type conversions. I switched the MySQL parameters to `varchar(5)` and the update exectued instantly.

Comment: True.  I augmented my Answer to clarify that.